# Unable to loop video using QML MediaPlayer

Tags: qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I am trying to create a simple video player that just plays a specified video on loop. While the video plays as expected, it does not loop.

The following is the code I am using:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import QtMultimedia 5.0

Rectangle
{
    width : 320
    height : 240

    signal buttonPressed(string msg)

    property string currentVideo

    function playVideo(videoName)
    {
        currentVideo = videoName
        videoPlayer.source = videoName
        videoPlayer.seek(1)
        videoPlayer.play()    
    }

    function loopVideo()
    {
        if(videoPlayer.duration === 0)
        {
            playVideo(currentVideo)
        }
    }

    function stopVideoPlayback()
    {
        videoPlayer.stop()  
    }

    MediaPlayer {
        id: videoPlayer
        source: ""
        autoPlay: false
        autoLoad: false
        loops: 100
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        source: videoPlayer
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: true
    }
}
```

I call `playVideo` from C++. It starts playing as expected. However, once it completes, the frame freezes on the last one. I tried looping it by calling the loopVideo function in a QTimer. That does not work either.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Your code is ok.** (slight tip: you might want to use `MediaPlayer.Infinite` instead `100` for looping)

I believe that your situation is same like mine.

I have played a little with `MediaPlayer` component and at my end I am unable to seek video because `seekable` is always `false`. And `seekable` is `false` because somehow QML uses my file as live stream, and that results `duration` property to be `0`.
Also note that `onPaused` and `onStopped` are never triggered and `position` is just increasing after end of video (live stream never ends).

Now I think that this is related to looping, because basically looping seeks back to 0. Because there is no `duration` (`MediaPlayer` thinks it is live stream) it cannot seek (and loop).

One nasty workaround that I found is this (append to your code):

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    //...

    MediaPlayer {
        //...
        onPositionChanged: {
            if (position > VIDEO_LENGTH) {
                root.stopVideoPlayback()
                root.playVideo(root.currentVideo)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `VIDEO_LENGTH` is length of your video file in milliseconds.

[Click here for MediaPlayer element documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html)

**UPDATE:**
[It looks like that is bug in Qt for mingw version (closed bug report).](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36488)

---

**UPDATE 2:** I have downloaded MSVC version of Qt and media player works as it is supposed.

So **it is bug in Qt for mingw**.

Either use this workaround (which I wouldn't recommend) or **download MSVC version**.

[I have created new bug report here.](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-43421)

Answer (score 0):

Using stopped  signal try this code :

```
 MediaPlayer {
     id: mediaplayer
     source: "groovy_video.mp4"
     onStopped: play()
}
```

Comment: Pleasae explain your answer. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.